# How do run a Unix command at a given  time interval?

Tags: unix, time, command, intervals

I want to run a Unix command (e.g. `ls`) at 5 minute intervals through a script.

### Explanation:

I have a Unix script. In that script I have a command called "ls".

I want that "ls" command to run every 5 minutes from that script.

Comment: Are you looking for concurrency?

Answer (score 13):

Use `watch`. The `-n` flag specifies interval in seconds, so

```
watch -n 300 ls
```

Comment: Unless of course you want this to happen every five minutes _always_. That would be a job for cron, but if you just want to do it occasionally, I'd recommend using `watch`.

Comment: Never used `watch` before. Cool stuff :)

Comment: I didn't have this on OS X, but obtained it quickly with `brew install watch`

Answer (score 9):

```
while true; do
    ls
    sleep 300
done
```

?

Comment: YES I think this is the easiest way

Comment: I think this is the easiest way

Comment: Well most people are suggesting you to use cron and such... but if I got the question right, it looks like you already have a script and want the `ls` every 5 minutes within the script. So again, if I'm right, cron doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 4):

Put your script into the Crontab via

```
crontab -e
```

More information about Cron you can find at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 2):

You could use crontab for example. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

for example i you want to run your script every five minutes via crontab it should look something like this:

```
#m  h dom mon dow user command
*/5 * *   *   *   root /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

or

```
svc
```

http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html