# print memory space of the pwd every 5 minutes

Tags: unix

I want a script that prints the memory space taken by the directory in every 5 minutes. I do not want to use a clone job. I wrote a bash script-

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "the script starts now"
sleep 60;
du -c > time&
```

But this does not work the way as expected.
I want to run this task in background and dump the space taken along with time to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following code

```
 du -c >> /var/log/messages &
 sleep 60s
```

Comment: This does not print anything

Comment: It will add du -c output to /var/log/messages file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command.

```
du -k path
```

Also, try to explore more options on du. Have you tried something on du?

Also refer to below question.

[How do run a Unix command at a given  time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758500/how-do-run-a-unix-command-at-a-given-time-interval)

Try below commands.

```
watch -n 300 du -s path
```

OR

```
while true; do
         du -s path
         sleep 300
done
```